# Cauchy and Convergent Sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Let X = {3, −4,3, −4,3, −4, ... }.
a) Show that X is not a Cauchy sequence in R.
b) Is X a convergent sequence in R? Justify your answer.

I am solving this exercise and i want to show that the sequence is not Cauchy. I put that the two subsequences of X { 3, 3, 3} and {-4, -4, -4} converge to different limits, so the sequence is not convergent therefore it is not Cauchy.
but in part 2 they asked about the convergence so I think what I did was wrong can any body help me to find other proof
thank you

Comment: If two subsequences converge to different values, the sequence is obviously not convergent.  What is your difficulty?

Comment: I want first to show that it is not Cauchy then show that it is not convergent i have 2 different questions

Comment: Not Cauchy implies not convergent- I still don't get what's bothering you.

Comment: i want to show that the sequence is not Cauchy using another proof.

Comment: i know that the absolute value of Xn - Xm must be greater than epsilon, how can i use tis proof here?

Comment: @herbsteinberg As the exercise is stated, it is obvious that one must not use the fact Cauchy is equivalent to convergent in $\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: can i say that the sequence is contractive because it s convergent and Cauchy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is ok. In the real numbers convergent iff Cauchy. If you want to use the definitions, without using the equivalence above, then, for part a), you can assume that the sequence is Cauchy, then for $\varepsilon=1>0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that, for  $n,m>N$ you have $|x_n-x_m|<1$. You get a contradiction if you take $n=N+1,\,m=N+2$, since you have $|x_{_{N+1}}-x_{_{N+2}}|=7>1$. For part b), you can use a similar argument.

Comment: thank you so much